# Lua raycasting anomaly

Tags: lua, raycasting

I have this **new** efficient raycasting code:

```
vectorX, vectorY = math.cos(r * math.pi/180), math.sin(r * math.pi/180)

wallDistanceX, wallDistanceY = v[3] - v[1], v[4] - v[2]
wallParallelX, wallParallelY = -wallDistanceY, wallDistanceX
rayX, rayY = v[1] - cam.x, v[2] - cam.y

Distance = (
    (rayX * wallParallelX) + (rayY * wallParallelY))/(
    (vectorX * wallParallelX) + (vectorY * wallParallelY)
)
if (
    (math.min(v[1],v[3]) <= (cam.x + (Distance * vectorX)) and math.max(v[1],v[3]) >= (cam.x + (Distance * vectorX))) and
        (math.min(v[2],v[4]) <= (cam.y + (Distance * vectorY)) and math.max(v[2],v[4]) >= (cam.y + (Distance * vectorY)))
) then
    table.insert(possibles, Distance)
else
    table.insert(possibles, 0)
end
```

This segment of code was converted to Lua from the answer of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2758173/the-distance-from-a-point-to-a-line-2-defined-points-with-a-vector) post, but when the rays are drawn, they look broken up, like this:

[image: anomalic rays]

I've done my debugging and so, and it turns out that when the ray is tested for intersection of a line, a distance of 0 is returned (a distance of 0 being returned means that the ray supposedly didn't intersect with a wall). There is a wall present as you see, and the minimap in the top-left corner shows just that.

Any ideas on why the ray is not being detected when it intersects? If you don't understand something pleeease ask.

`r = angle for ray`

`v = an index of the list {}; v[i] is either the x1,y1,x2,y2 of the line`

Comment: You are comparing floating point numbers!  Replace `math.min(v[1],v[3]) <= (cam.x + (Distance * vectorX))` with `math.min(v[1],v[3]) - eps < (cam.x + (Distance * vectorX))` and so on, where `eps = 1e-9`

Comment: It now renders nothing when I do that; looks like [this](https://imgur.com/a/Lhy0mqJ).

Comment: Show your new code

Comment: https://pastebin.com/2iM8Gan7

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/jCcu66H

Comment: Replace `max()` with `max() + eps` and `min()` with `min() - eps`.  Do not use `floor`.

Comment: That improves things; the walls are all solid, but some aren't rendered [here](https://imgur.com/a/vUPNEMy)

Comment: New code is [here](https://pastebin.com/0qiCX14M)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170141/discussion-between-crazicrafter1-and-egor-skriptunoff).